# How to show my layout in front off soft keyboard Android?

Tags: android, emoji, whatsapp, soft-keyboard

How to show my layout in front off soft keyboard Android like whatsapp or facebook?
like this

[image]

thanks before

this my code, but when emoji layout show, soft keyboard close.

```
btn_pop_emot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (listEmot.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                listEmot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
                        edt_pop_komen.getApplicationWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                btn_pop_emot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.emot_anim);

            } else {
                listEmot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt_pop_komen.getWindowToken(),
                        0);
                btn_pop_emot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keyboard);

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I believe they calculate the EditText position after the soft keyboard is shown, and when you click on the emojicon button, it will show the layout beneath the EditText but they set the height of the emojicon layout height as the keyboard height.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library, it also contains sample code in README to get you started
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon